# Verbose log when using pandas in unit tests

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, logging

I am trying to write unit tests for a python codebase that I have. When I import pandas and run the tests, I get this very verbose output:

```
$HOME=XXXX
CONFIGDIR=XXXX/.config/matplotlib
matplotlib data path: XXXX/anaconda3/envs/YYYY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
loaded rc file XXXX/anaconda3/envs/YYYY/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
matplotlib version 3.1.1
interactive is False
platform is linux
loaded modules: ['builtins', 'sys', ...
```

(Of course I XXXX'd and YYYY'd the personal information.) Those logs appear without following the rules of my logger, so I assume they come from either matplotlib or pandas, I don't know. I've seen this problem before but I don't remember what the answer was to mute those logs; it's quite annoying to have them, especially since the last line is an extremely long list (700+ strings averaging 20-30 characters).

How would I go and remove those? I really don't need them. I tried to produce a minimal working example, but within my codebase, if I have the following test file, I produce the log:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
import pandas as pd

# Logging
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(levelname)s %(asctime)s -- %(name)s: %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        # logging.FileHandler("example1.log"),
        logging.StreamHandler()
    ],
)
```

and if I run the same file outside my codebase (with the same conda environment, everything I can think of is the same, feel free to ask for suggestions in the comments of things I might have missed...), the problem doesn't happen. So that's as far as it gets for a MWE.

Comment: Those are matplotlib logging.  Don’t use basicConfig if you don’t want every modules output.  You can set the log level by logger name instead.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Ahhh ok! Thanks a lot, super helpful. Feel free to convert that into an answer!